# ASP.NET on button click event

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Hello I'm new to cshtml and I have web pages in ASP.NET Razor v2 I would like to insert some data into DB on button click. These data are provided from various textboxes and also uploading picture. May I please know how to how to provide action on button click?

I tried this in my cshtml file :

```
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="insertRegistered">Uložit</button>
    @if (action == "insertRegistered")
    {
    var db1 = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var sql = "UPDATE services SET FileName=@0, FileContent=@1, MimeType=@2 WHERE IDservice=6";
    db1.Execute(sql, fileName, fileContent, fileMime);
    }
```

Comment: There's a nice tutorial for the beginners [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WebMatrix, you can accomplish this in this way:

Razor code:

```
@{
    var fileName = "";
    var fileContent = "";
    var fileMime = "";
    var IDservice = "";

     @*TEST CODE *@
    @*if (!IsPost)
    {

        IDservice = "1";
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE IDservice = @0";
        var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, IDservice);
        fileContent = row.fileContent;
        fileMime = row.MimeType;
        fileName = row.fileName;
    } *@

    if (IsPost)
    {
        fileName = Request.Form["fileName"];
        fileContent = Request.Form["fileContent"];
        fileMime = Request.Form["fileMime"];
        IDservice = Request.Form["IDservice"];
        var db1 = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var sql = "UPDATE services SET FileName=@0, FileContent=@1, MimeType=@2 WHERE IDservice=@3";
        db1.Execute(sql, fileName, fileContent, fileMime, IDservice);
    } 
}
```

And the markup should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Service</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Service Information</legend>

            <p><label for="fileName">FileName:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fileName" value="@fileName" /></p>

            <p><label for="fileContent">File Content:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fileContent" value="@fileContent" /></p>

            <p><label for="fileMime">Mime:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fileMime" value="@fileMime" /></p>

            <input type="hidden" name="IDservice" value="@IDservice" />

            <p>  <button type="submit" name="action" value="insert Registered">Uložit</button></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's a working [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0ajZKbmx0TTRhdUE/edit?usp=sharing).

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2)'s a set of tutorials which, I believe, should be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Put your database logic into a controller action, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do database update logic here

            // Upon successfully updating the database redirect to a view 
            // that displays the information, read-only version not editable
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // If something went wrong, then re-display the view 
            // the user tried to update database from
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your view create a form by using the HTML helper `Html.BeginForm()`, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName","ControllerName"))
{
    ... your input, labels, textboxes and other html controls go here
    <input class="button" id="submit" type="submit" value="Uložit" />
}
```

> Note: `Html.BeginForm()` will take everything inside of it and submit that as the form data to the controller action specified as parameters to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. May I know which namespace should I use in the class?

Comment: @Marek - namespace in a class, I am not sure what you mean. Classes are contained within namespaces, so are you asking what namespace the class should be put in? You should already have a `Home` folder in the `Controllers` directory of your solution.

Comment: I created new class named HomeController.cs put there your code but Visual Studio cannot recognize `AcceptVerbs`,`ActionResult`, `FormColeection` and it doesn't offer me to add some `using namespace`. I think i messed up something, didn't I? i'm using ASP.NET with engine Razor v2. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Did you create an ASP.NET MVC application using the Visual Studio template?

Comment: Yes I did. Now I added System.Web.Mvc.dll and it finally recognizes everything except BeginForm in cshtml file (the one with button) Error: `'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I'm not sure what should I correct now. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Marek - your code looks like Webpages, not MVC. Can you please clarify? Aren't you using Webmatrix?

Comment: @afzalulh I believe it is WebMatrix. when I click in Visual Studio 2012 File - New - Website - Installed - Templates - Visual c# I choose ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2) it is some kind of template from Microsoft. That is the reason why I tagget this only with asp.net because I wasn't sure what should I tag. Thank you again.

Comment: @Marek you have created a Razor Web Pages site. The code from Karl Anderson is for MVC. You can't mix the two. Remove the System.Web.Mvc.dll and ignore everything to do with controllers. You should look at afzalulh's answer.